# Renewing User Access Token using Instagram Basic Display

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

From the looks of the Instagram Basic Display API docs, it looks like both the auth code and access token expire after 1 hour. Is there any way to renew the access token without requiring the user to log in every time?

Link to relevant docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview

Comment: I'm sure this must be a typo on their side. A token that expires in 1 hour would be completely useless.

Comment: You would think, right? But I'm getting this error from the API after an hour:

"Error validating access token: Session has expired on Tuesday, 22-Oct-19 08:00:00 PDT. The current time is Tuesday, 22-Oct-19 08:22:03 PDT."

Comment: A bug has been filed: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/3109002399171119/. Although it seems this is per design and not a typo.

Comment: Wow, like you mentioned in your comment on that thread, this makes the API pretty useless if we have to constantly re-authenticate users. Let's see how facebook responds to your comment

Comment: Please take a look at the question related this on the community discussion thread: https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/2348548148794443/ Hopefully with enough support this will be considered.

Comment: Seems like we're not the only ones with this issue. This discussion thread is 6 days old and is trending higher https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/446420572897396/ it may be worth a comment on too

Comment: Maybe I'll file a bug that they've incorrectly named their API when there is next to no functionality to display images

Comment: i wish i had submitted my instagram app before 15th. at least i wouldve delivered my task. a 1 hours token is useless.

Comment: any news about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for Long-Lived Access Tokens has been added to the Basic Display API.

Here is the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/long-lived-access-tokens